# Storing a document with html to Elastic Search

Tags: c#, html, elasticsearch

I am trying to index elastic search with some content after stripping out the html. I fail to find proper examples after searching.

I have seen this:

http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Strip-HTML-on-indexing-does-not-store-results-td3039614.html

and this:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/1026

No follow up. My question, should i strip of html before indexing or is there something custom in Elastic search to get this done?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [html strip filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-htmlstrip-charfilter.html). It makes sure what you search is only on the text of the HTML ( and not the div or body tag texts ) and gives you back the HTML as result

Comment: do u have a code sample for that. i fail to find a sample code.